# Validate Window's global hook state

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, setwindowshookex

I'm using **SetWindowsHookEx** to set a global hook to capture all key strokes, unfortunately I'm facing an issue where after a certain period of time, the hook is possibly removed and i no longer receive new key strokes.

According MSDN, there is a registry key that defines the upper threshold of time callbacks can process messages before the hook is removed. This behavior happens randomly after a few hours / days without the callback being invoked. Is it possible to design a watchdog to first examine HOOK's state (valid / present) and only then set it using **SetWindowsHookEx** if needed?

**Edit** : From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx):

> the hook procedure should process a message in less time than the data
>   entry specified in the LowLevelHooksTimeout value in the following
>   registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop The value is in
>   milliseconds. If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the
>   message to the next hook. However, on Windows 7 and later, the hook is
>   silently removed without being called. There is no way for the
>   application to know whether the hook is removed.

Comment: It would be nice if you added a link to the MSDN article describing the time threshold / registry key....

Comment: See modified question

Comment: Pretty common to pay *too much* attention to the timeout.  It is a simple counter-measure against misbehaving hooks that make the user lose control over his machine.  Problem is, you tend to discover this too early when trying to debug the hook code.  In which case it is reasonable to use a very large timeout, although it is not much joy to try to debug without a keyboard or mouse.  After which you should not do *anything* to prevent any remaining but undetected bugs from having the user lose control of the machine.  "It stopped working" is better than "I had to uninstall your product".

Comment: Oh - I'd thought from your own description that you'd found another timeout on the total period of inactivity for a hook handler (e.g. 2 days since last call = auto-unhook).  Given it's limiting processing time per event callback Hans has good advice, but would emphasise that the actions in the callback should be carefully crafted to do as little as possible, for example it may be better to enqueue something of the event and have another periodic timer clear that queue.

Comment: *"the hook is possibly removed and i no longer receive new key strokes"* - So is it removed by the system, or is another hook installed to the front of the hook chain, which doesn't pass input events down to your hook?

Comment: If you use the [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(.aspx) to capture keyboard input, you won't suffer from this issue anymore. And even MSDN recommends using Raw Input instead of a hook.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, given the answer you've just provided, is the order of the messages guaranteed? meaning, if the user typed "hello world bla bla", after parsing the messages, i'd get the same result?

Comment: @igalk yes, the order is guaranteed

Comment: Can you post it as an answer so I'd accept it?